# Как интерпретировать понятие "высоконагруженное Android приложение"?

Tags: android, highload, задание-на-собеседовании

На одном собеседовании на позицию Android developer мне был задан вопрос: "*Имею ли я опыт создания **высоконагруженных Android приложений**.*" (Жаль, что мысль уточнить определение этого понятия мне пришла уже после собеседования)

Разработкой приложений для Android я занимаюсь уже несколько лет. Так получилось, что проекты с которыми я работаю(л) не имели большого успеха в плане количества пользователей. Исходя из этого, на вышеупомянутый вопрос я ответил, что такого опыта не имел, все проекты доростали в лучшем случае до нескольки тысяч пользователей. (В данном случае, я интерпретировал highload как количество активных пользователей)

Ранее я не встречал применение понятия "высоконагруженный" (highload) в контексте Android приложений. И сейчас, задавшись вопросом я вижу, что это понятие применяется по отношению к бекенду и сайтам.

После проведения аналогий с highload в вебе, я бы сказал, что highload Android app - это приложение архитектура которого будет легко поддерживать внедрение новых функций, оптимально расходовать ресурсы Android девайса. Но разве не каждое приложение должно разрабатываться с учетом этих требований?

Хочу поинтересоваться у других специалистов, как вы понимаете "высоконагруженный" (hihgload) по отношению к Android приложению?

Comment: Думаю, это просто неудачный вопрос на собеседовании, одна установка приложения все-таки обслуживает одного пользователя. Скорее всего имелось в виду, был ли опыт разработки приложения **для** сервиса с высокой нагрузкой.

Comment: @etki а какие могут быть особенности разработки клиента для сервиса с высокой нагрузкой?

Comment: @andreycha например минимизация количества запросов к серверу + грамотная обработка задержек/недоступности бэкенда

Comment: @rjhdby мне кажется, это вещи, справедливые для всех приложений, которые общаются с сервисом.

Comment: @andreycha вот видно, что вы тоже не разрабатывали высоконагруженные :) Да, конечно, к этому надо стремиться всегда, но, например, в "казуальном" приложении вполне можно обойтись JSON'ом с человекочитаемыми полями, доступным по запросу и не заморачиваться ужатыми вусмерть бинарными форматами кешируемыми в локальном SQLite и обновляемыми инкрементально

Comment: @rjhdby вот это уже ближе к делу :).

Comment: @andreycha это к собеседующим вопрос, но вообще клиент должен быть готовым к тому, что бэкенд может лопнуть

Comment: Приложения, при большом объёме данных, начинают тормозить. Например, мобильный клиент социальной сети может стать очень медленным, когда у пользователя 1000 друзей или 1000 фотографий.

Comment: @owasp, не может... Если все прямыми руками распаралеллено - работает нормально. Поток входных данных не может быть быстрее скорости отображения. Под эти две задачи заточено, как минимум, 2 потока - а у телефонов от 2-х и более ядер.

Comment: Вобще не существует такого понятия - точнее критериев его оценки.
Скорее говорят о "масштабировании в ширину". Те высоконагруженное приложение - приложение способное грамотно масштабироваться в ширину при увеличении количества запросов к нему.

Comment: У меня каждое второе приложение масштабируется в ширину. Настолько в ширину, что просто выползает из компьютера и аварийно прибивается. Хватит такого масштабирования!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сложно сказать, что именно имели в виду на собеседовании, но я могу предположить следующие ситуации:

- Собеседование проводил нетехнический специалист, у которого был опросник (или опыт) для собеседования бекенд-специалистов, который на лету как-то адаптировал вопросы, а в ответах надеялся услышать уверенный ответ (не важно какой)
- Собеседование проводил грамотный интервьюер, вопрос задавался с целью проверить уверенность знаний или ввести в некий стресс. Ожидаемым ответом на такие вопросы являются уточняющие вопросы или рассказ о том, что вопрошающий спрашивает чушь.
- Собеседник разговаривает на каком-то внутреннем диалекте, известном только ему или его окружению. В этом случае он хотел узнать что-то конкретное, но вот что именно - остается только гадать.

И если с первыми 2 случаями все относительно понятно, то в последнем варианте можно подумать о:

1. Отзывчивости и плавности приложения, особенно когда оно обвешано сторонними модулями и библиотеками. Мне порой попадались приложения, которые на топовом железе прошлого года выдавали ну просто сверх-тормозящие списочки. Впрочем, гигагерцы и ядра только растут, а списочки все равно всегда тормозят.
2. Оптимизации сетевого обмена с сервером. Когда сервер задыхается от миллионов запросов, то тут надо бы подумать, как сделать работу сервера попроще. К примеру, отказаться от XML/JSON и других человекочитаемых протоколов, как бы ввести несколько серверов, как бы снизить число запросов так, чтобы и функциональность не пострадала, и при этом сервер без лишней надобности не трогать. Надо сказать, что это в общем-то не работа Андроид-девелопера, но порой больше этим некому заниматься. Вопрос мог означать, умеете ли вы работать с байтиками или ума хватает только на парсинг XML и голые запросы по http.
3. Иногда надо работать с большими объемами данных. К примеру, отображать карту с миллионами объектов на ней одновременно. Да, это возможно, но если все приложение написать на сишечке, а не использовать гугломапсы, как это делают все.
4. Есть ряд приложений, где отзывчивость критически важна и которые потребляют максимум ресурсов. К примеру, Angry Birds делает внутри себя какую-то магию, что мой планшет становится горячим примерно за 10 минут игры. Я не знаю как они этого добились, но я верю, что это пример высоконагруженного приложения
5. Майнинг биткоинов, подсчет прогноза погоды, рисование чего-то поверх фотографий на основе нейросетей. Возможно, в скрытом режиме. Наверное злые птицы чем-то таким в фоне и занимаются.

Думаю, список можно продолжать бесконечно. Если кто-то напишет другие варианты, то будет круто.

А вообще, порог входа в профессию "погромизд на андроид" настолько низок, что достаточно понимать как правильно копипастить код со стековерфлоу и клеить свои приложения из копипасты. АПИ меняется постоянно, равно как и практики, равно как и требования. Я совершенно не понимаю, зачем проводят такие собеседования.